# Связь андроид с онлайн базой данных

Tags: php, java, android, mysql

Создаю приложение на андроид. Необходимо, чтобы данные при регистрации участников сохранялись на сервере. Уже неделю роюсь в Интернете... Пытаюсь найти как это делается. И все решения уже не работают... post запросы не работают, с php скриптами связываться не хочет, сервлеты тоже уже отключены. Как быть? Каково современное решение проблемы, если мне надо сохранить в серверной базе дынных данные о пользователях. СПАСИБО заранее))

P.S. Код не могу предоставить по причине того, что его и нет. У меня есть переменные со значениями, это надо отправить в базу данных. Вот

Comment: Код предоставьте

Comment: Делите задачу на подзадачу. Если у вас не работают post-запросы, то покажите, как вы их выполняете и что не получается.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно смотреть RESTfull API + JSON

На Android можно/нужно использовать Retrofit2 как http клиент, документация на офф.сайте.
В качестве архитектуры смотрите MVP/MVVM, для начала можете просто не запариваться, с первого раза не получится, как трудно поддержка пойдет тогда думайте.